# How to initialise a class variable with __init__()?

Tags: python, class, oop

As I understand, a class property can be used in a sense as the static variable for Python. I have a class and I would like to set this static variable during the first run of `__init__()`, i.e. when the first object is being created and to keep it like that. Not to update it each time. What should I do exactly? Even setting a flag doesn't help.

```
class A():
    foo=None
    foo_set_flag=False
    def __init__(self,arg_foo):
        if not self.foo_set_flag:
            self.foo=arg_foo
            foo_set_flag=True
a=A(12)
b=A(13)
print a.foo
print b.foo
```

which gives:

```
12
13
```

and of course I expect

```
12
12
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ClassName.attribute_name` to access class attribute:

```
class A:
    foo = None
    foo_set_flag = False

    def __init__(self, arg_foo):
        if not A.foo_set_flag:
            A.foo = arg_foo
            A.foo_set_flag = True

a=A(12)
b=A(13)
print a.foo # -> 12
print b.foo # -> 12
```

`self.foo = ...` creates a new instance attribute. Reading `self.foo` will access class attribute only if there is no instance attribute `foo`, otherwise it access the instnace variable `foo`.

Comment: However this solution will fail if the class name is changed and require modification of the function. I think my solution is better.

Comment: @RamchandraApte, I don't think make `__ini__` method itself a class mehtod is not a good idea. IMHO, making a separated class method and calling it from the `__init__` is more reasonable.

Comment: Why? If you need to access the instance then you can move the portions which need the class method into a separate function.

Comment: @RamchandraApte And how would you call it? If `__init__` is a classmethod, it doesn't have access to `self`, so you can't call functions on the instance. Beyond that, the same thing could be achieved without using `@classmethod` by doing `type(self)`. Either way, this is a bad idea as you don't know that the instance isn't of a subclass - hence you would potentially start messing with the wrong class.

Comment: @Lattyware You could move the parts requiring access of the class into a function decorated by `@classmethod`.

Comment: @RamchandraApte And how will you call that? Using the class name or `type(self)`. Either way, the same problems exist, you have just moved the problem.

Comment: @Lattyware You could just use `self.classmethod_function`.

Comment: @RamchandraApte And again, if the class has been subclassed, you will be modifying the subclass, not the class you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `self`, refer to the class itself:

```
def __init__(self,arg_foo):
    if not A.foo_set_flag:
        A.foo=arg_foo
        A.foo_set_flag=True
```

Or, you don't even need the flags to achieve this:

```
>>> class A():
    foo = None
    def __init__(self, arg_foo):
        if A.foo is not None:
            A.foo = arg_foo


>>> a = A(10)
>>> b = A(20)
>>> print(a.foo)
10
>>> print(b.foo)
10
```